# Where is the linux sysroot placed?

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake

I am new to yocto so please be nice. When bitbaking a raspberrypi image, I got the final images in `tmp/deploy`.

I know the kernel-source is in `downloads`, but what about the final sources. Where is the patched kernel? Also where is the uncompressed image within all their libraries placed?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Answer (score 1):

usually it is located at `/tmp/sysroots`

Comment: This folder is empty. Do I need to explicitly build it?

Comment: Thx! OK, there it is! Does it have effects, when I change the kernel sources here? My guess is, that it will be replaced every new build.

Comment: yes, what you change there will be used to create the images